# Android calendar event not being added

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to add an event to the calendar, this event should be repeated hourly every 3 hours, I wrote the following code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, cal.getTimeInMillis())
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000)
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Medication Alert")
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "It's time to take the medication")
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Home")
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=3")
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "xyz@gmail.com");
        startActivity(intent);
```

When running the code, the calendar opens, when I press "save" a toast is shown ("event is created"), when I check the calendar in my app it shows no event created.

If I remove the following line :

```
.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=3")
```

the event is successfully created and saved, but I need to repeat the event every 3 hours, any help please ?